# What is the best role grouping for my project?

Tags: roles, requirements

I am at the beginning of my website project and now for requirements step I want to grouping the roles of website users,there is three roles for the users:

1. Users who visit the website an use it's free services.
2. Users who have an account and uses it's more free services.
3. Users who have an account and monthly pay for using paid services.
4. Admin user of the website.

What is the best roles for these users?

Comment: I see 4 roles there. What's the trouble?

Comment: It looks like you've defined the roles already.  So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: For instance I define  user stories such as 1. The user create an account and 2. the user pay for services, so the roles of  users change by their actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have two roles:

1. Admin
2. User

The User role seems to be separated into three tiers or types:

1. Unregistered users
2. Registered Users
3. Paid/Subscription Users

That's how you need to be thinking about your groups of users. Admins don't really count unless you have special privileges. How you treat your different levels of users is very important however since I assume your goal is to "land and expand". i.e. Lure in users with free services, get them to register with further offerings and then get them to pay for even more advanced levels of service.

Comment: "Land and expand", your guess was true however I haven't heard about "land and expand" before.so in whole of my user stories i just use the two roles?

Comment: For your user stories I think you will want to use all the role names however appropriate. Your handling of the different user types will certainly have different goals.